# Why not multiply Electrical power with stepup transformers?

Tags: transformer

I saw youtube video showing a stepup transformer(from microwave) double the electricity than input. 12v input and 120v output.

why not its possible if connect many stepup transformers(1st transformer secondary will be primary to 2nd transformer) in series and generate million amps electricity from just 12v. ?

Comment: Elemental physics.

Comment: To be fair to the questioner, he's actually asking why you *can't* generate huge amounts of power (i.e. what prevents you from doing that). I don't think he's seriously suggesting you could, but rather realises there's a gap in his (limited) knowledge and wants to understand what he's missing

Comment: this is the video i was talking about [link]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tyvZGIlHEok there are other videos which shows from 12v to KV generators, i just wanted to know how true those videos are.

Comment: Just leaving aside the terminology you used and concentrating on Voltage Step-Up devices. This is possible using an inverter. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_inverter . Inverters are **very common** devices e.g. Solar Panel Inverters. They don't break the laws of physics as pointed out by very many of the other contributors. But they do work, and are usually based on Switching Power Converters.

Comment: you mean to say we can generate KV from 12V ? or high voltage from low voltage ?

Comment: @Rudy, yes, sort of. Power is a combination of current and voltage. You can keep the power the same (theoretically, with 100% efficiency) but shift the current up and lower the voltage, or raise the voltage but lower the current. You CANNOT shift from some power to a higher power, as that means creating energy... which (to all known physics) is impossible.

Answer (score 9):

You can't passively "multiply" any type of power by any means, including multiplying electrical power by using a transformer.

Electrical power is voltage times current.  A transformer can change the relative voltage and current, but can never create a higher voltage x current (power) out than in.  In fact, since there will inevitably be some losses, real transformers will always produce *less* power out than in.

You are also need to learn the right terms.  Saying that you are doubling "electricity" is meaningless.  Do you mean voltage, current, power, or something else?

A transformer can create higher output current than input current, but this comes at the expense of lower voltage.  There is no free lunch.  Likewise, a transformer can create higher voltage but at the expense of lower current.

For example, it is possible to take normal "wall power" at 110 V and use a transformer to run a neon sign that might take 2.2 kV, for a voltage step up ratio of 20.  If the neon sign draws 10 mA at 2.2 kV, then the transformer must draw at least 200 mA from the 110 V AC power supply it is connected to.  For a more real world example, let's say the transformer is 85% efficient.  The output is 2.2 kV x 10 mA = 22 Watts.  The input to the transformer therefore requires 22 W / 85% = 26 W.  If the input is 110 V, then the transformer will draw 26 W / 110 V = 240 mA.  The 4 W that went into the transformer but didn't come out as electrical power end up heating the transformer.

Comment: i dunno electrical terms, by using transformers if you are multipling the current then it will drain input in same amount[in your words - a transformer can create higher voltage but at the expense of lower current.] if so as per your theory it should drain lower current source if someone trying generate higher current, but in this video [link]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u3A2dFgKbbE same 9v battery still works... HOW ?

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, good idea. Too bad we have to live with the Law of Conservation of Energy. Look that up on Wikipedia. Also, you'll want to look up Ohm's Law and it's corollary which equates power (watts) to voltage and current: P = V * I. Power (e.g. watts) is defined as energy use per unit of time ( e.g. Joules per second ).

Put this all together and you will find, as many before you, that when it comes to electric power you can't get somethin for nothin.  That only happens on Wall Street and on TV.

When you use a tranformer to convert AC voltage up or down in voltage, the current capability is inversely proportional, and the power ( V * I ) is maintained constant. Double the voltage, halve the current capability. Halve the voltage, double the current capability. If this weren't the case, we wouldn't have needed all those hydoelectric plants and nuclear reactors we spent trillions of dollars to build. Instead, we would all have a transformer connected to a AAA battery in our basements.

Comment: Geesh, physics can be so incovenient sometimes!

Comment: "Our power plant shut down"

"What happened?"

"Eh it's nothing, Bill just needs to stop by CVS to pick up a AAA battery"

Comment: What does Ohm's law have to do with this, and what makes you think that the equation for power is a corollary?

Comment: so how come a 9V battery generate spark which supposed be generated only with KV and that 9v is not drained on the fly even after many attempts of high voltage use. video link is posted in my above comment

Answer (score 1):

So the real question is, **"How is it possible that tiny batteries create extreme high voltage?"**

Heh, the real answer: voltage is not energy.   Big impressive sparks are usually low-energy, low-wattage on average.  Their voltage may be high, but their energy is feeble.

For example, a big VandeGraaff electrostatic generator which produces 2ft sparks, on average it only uses a watt or two.  Two hundred thousand volts at 10 microamps, that's only two watts.  That's less than a flashlight.

Voltage is not energy.   So in theory, we could make billion-volt lightning bolts using a tiny coin-cell from a hearing-aid.  In theory.

A transformer is like step-up gears, or like a lever.   If you use a very long lever, you can lift a thousand pounds by pushing the lever with your fingertip.  Make your lever longer and you can lift a million pounds.  The forces are immense, but the total amount of work remains tiny.

And, if you wind enough turns of wire on your HV transformer, you can create high kilovolts using a tiny battery.  Adding more turns of wire is like using a longer lever.  But the watts don't increase.   If you can light a fire using five watts of heating in a tungsten wire, you can light a fire with five watts of heating in a 10-kilovolt spark discharge.